# Why doesn't the following code work?

Tags: c, pointers, initialization

1. The following code attempts to create a new variable of type presence( a kind of structure) but when I run it through gdb, it shows that the variable has the same address in every iteration? Shouldn't a local variable get a different address when it is being redeclared?

   ```
   presence* hashtable[MAX];
   int i = 0;

   printf("---------ENTERING DATA FOR THE HASHTABLE------------------\n");
   while (i < MAX)
   {

           presence item; /* Same address on every iteration */
           printf("Enter item id : ");
           scanf("%d",&item.id);

           printf("Enter item name : ");
           item.name = (char*)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(char));
           getchar();
           fgets(item.name,SIZE,stdin);

           putItem(hashtable,&item);
           i++;

   }
   ```
2. When a item of type presence is put inside the hashtable, should I allocate the memory and then assign item or do it simply(refer the following code)

   ```
   int putItem(presence* hashtable[], presence* item)
   {
       int key = hash(item->id);
       hashtable[key] = (presence*)malloc(sizeof(presence)); /* Required or not? or do the below straight away?*/
       hashtable[key] = item;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1: You should have `presence *item;` pointer type variable, allocate it and use it to fill the data. Your current implementation uses same variable in each iteration.

```
while (i < MAX)
{

        presence *item; /* pointer */
        item = malloc(sizeof(*item));
        printf("Enter item id : ");
        scanf("%d",&item->id);

        printf("Enter item name : ");
        item->name = (char*)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(char));
        getchar();
        fgets(item->name,SIZE,stdin);

        putItem(hashtable,item);
        i++;

}
```

For 2: You don't need to allocate memory. The line

```
hashtable[key] = (presence*)malloc(sizeof(presence));
```

is not needed.

However make sure `key` is less than `MAX` which is size of `hashtable`. Also, you may want to handle clashes appropriately.

Comment: I would also add that local variables do not persist beyond their scope, which is also fixed by using a pointer and allocating memory.

Comment: Everything makes so much sense. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Your local variables are volatile.  When you create an instance, it disappears when the variable goes out of scope.  So, you may get the same address in the following iteration.

In the seconds instance, you do need to `malloc` the space for `presence` and need to copy it using `memcpy`.  Instead of using `hashtable[key] = item`, you should do `memcpy ( hashtable[key], item, sizeof ( item ) );`

Answer (score 1):

1. Local variables typically get only one address. As the variable `item` goes out of scope on the loop's back edge, the compiler is free to reuse its storage on the next execution of the loop. Either way, storing a pointer to a local variable to a data structure that lives longer than the scope of the local variable is a bad idea.
2. Depends on what you need: if the values in the hash table should be independent of the values that are passed in you should allocate memory in the function. If they shouldn't, then not.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't a local variable get a different address when it is being redeclared?

I don't see why it is a must (for any variable). In fact, it's quite a logical decision for a compiler to place it at the same memory location.

But anyway, the approach you are currently taking is wrong: you are using the address of a local (block-scope automatic) variable after it's out of scope, which is undefined behavior. You should allocate memory dynamically for the individual elements instead.

> When a item of type presence is put inside the hashtable, should I allocate the memory and then assign item or do it simply

Does "simply" mean "without allocating memory"?

Apart from that, this completely depends on what the contract between different functions is. Also, allocate memory **for what?** In your particular case, these lines:

```
hashtable[key] = (presence*)malloc(sizeof(presence));
hashtable[key] = item;
```

would leak memory since you are overwriting the pointer to the allocated memory right after having allocated it. So no, don't do the memory allocation. But, if you hadn't declared the **hash table** (not the items inside it!) as

```
presence* hashtable[MAX];
```

(i. e. an array of pointers) but you had a pointer-to-pointers:

```
presence **hashtable;
```

you **would have had to** allocate memory for the hash table (outside the insertion function, obviously):

```
presence **hashtable = malloc(sizeof(*hashtable) * N_ITEMS);
```

---

Also, please **[do NOT cast the return value of `malloc()`!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)**